# How can I return an array of integers from Solana rust program function to front end?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-cli, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

I don't know how can I write a smart contract in Solana that after executing the logic, returns an array of integers, strings, ... to the client, and how can I fetch it using Web3?

Answer (score 2):

There's a syscall available to on-chain programs called `set_return_data`, which puts data into a buffer that can be read by the higher-level programs using `get_return_data`.  This all mediated through opaque byte buffers, so you'll need to know how to decode the response.

If you want to fetch the data from the client side, you can simulate the transaction and read the data back from the `return_data` field in the response: https://edge.docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#results-50

The RPC support in simulated transactions is very new in version 1.11, but the return data is available in earlier versions.

Source code for `set_return_data` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/658752cda710cb358d7ccbbc2cee06bf8009c2d4/sdk/program/src/program.rs#L102

Source code for `get_return_data` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/658752cda710cb358d7ccbbc2cee06bf8009c2d4/sdk/program/src/program.rs#L117

Answer (score 0):

So, programs do not return data (other than success or failure).

However; most programs write data to a program owned account's `data` field and this could be read from client apps (Rust, Python, TS/JS, etc.).

If using the Solana web3 library, you can call `getAccountInfo` on the `Connection` object. This will return the byte array of the account. You will then need to `deserialize` that data. You have to know how the program `serializes` the data to reverse it successfully.

Check the Solana Cookbook for overview using `borsh` https://solanacookbook.com/guides/serialization.html#how-to-deserialize-account-data-on-the-client

Comment: See more recent option, defined in Jon C answer, to this question.